# Services not loaded at Resources/config/services.yml, why?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.7

I'm running a issue here and I don't know why or where this is failing, perhaps I miss some configuration or so, anyway, I have this code at `DependencyInjection\AppExtension.php` file:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Then at `Resources/config/services.yml` I have this:

```
services:
    pdone.twig.extension:
        class: GroupDCA\PDOneBundle\Extension\PDOneTwigExtension
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

For some reason isn't working. This mean I got this error:

> The filter "empty" does not exist in PDOneBundle::pdone.html.twig at line 1

Now if I move the services definition to `config/config.yml` I got this error instead:

> Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Which makes me think the bundle is not going through DependecyInjection, what I am missing here? Why different errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Did you add your bundle to `AppKernel`?

2) I am not sure, but I think you must follow the naming convention of your `Extension` class:

- Bundle's root directory should contain `DependencyInjection` directory
- Within the `DependencyInjection`, `Extension` class should be named as `<BUNDLE>Extension`, without "Bundle" suffix. That would be `PDOOneExtension` in your case.

Comment: Ups, naming convention I made a mistake `AppExtension` should be `PDOneExtension` it's working now